# Life of flash drive and ReadyBoost

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I've seen many articles about flash drive life expectancy. They say that the life of flash drive is about 10,000 write cycles. Is this true or just a myth?

Second, Microsoft Windows Vista and 7 have a feature called 'ReadyBoost' which uses flash drives to speed booting. If flash drives really do have a short life expectancy then will using ReadyBoost greatly reduce the life of a flash drive?

Comment: Not really programming related.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [it is true](https://www.storagesearch.com/ssdmyths-endurance.html); flash drives have a limited number of writes cycles.

From this [ReadyBoost Q&A][2] article:

> Q: Won't this wear out the drive?
>
> A: Nope. We're aware of the
> lifecycle issues with flash drives and are smart about how and when we
> do our writes to the device. Our research shows that we will get at
> least 10+ years out of flash devices that we support.

Answer (score 0):

They're program/erase cycles. And they're no myth and there's no way around it. Only thing you can do it try is make wear occur evenly across all NAND cells.

More sophisticated NAND based drives take care of this themselves. It's transparent and invisible to the operating system.

However, a modern operating system can help the NAND drive's firmware by telling it which sectors are no longer containing useful data using for example the ATA TRIM command. Other protocols like NVMe or even SD implement their own command set and TRIM like commands.

But however smart you do this, eventually a NAND drive wears out.

[image]